# Receiving Error in Workflow activity code

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity, query-expressions

I am receiving the following error in my code:

Condition for attribute 'sgfdhr_leavetype.new_employeeleavecalculation': expected argument(s) of type 'System.Guid' but received 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference'.

My code is below:

```
public int Getleavetype(Entity LeaveManagement, IOrganizationService _orgService, CodeActivityContext Acontext)
        {
      QueryExpression GetLeavedetails = new QueryExpression();
      GetLeavedetails.EntityName = "sgfdhr_leavetype";
      GetLeavedetails.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_type");
      GetLeavedetails.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_availabledays");
      GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_type", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1);
      GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_employeeleavecalculation",    ConditionOperator.Equal,LeaveManagement["new_leavedetails"]);
            EntityCollection LeaveDetails = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetLeavedetails);
            return (int)LeaveDetails[0]["new_availabledays"];
        }
```

I am recieving error on " EntityCollection LeaveDetails = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetLeavedetails);" this line in above code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear you have this condition:

```
 GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_employeeleavecalculation", ConditionOperator.Equal, LeaveManagement["new_leavedetails"]);
```

The error is telling you that `LeaveManagement["new_leavedetails"]` is an `EntityReference` (lookup) and not a `Guid`

You can cast the field before and after put the `Id` inside the condition:

```
EntityReference detailsRef = (EntityReference)LeaveManagement["new_leavedetails"];
GetLeavedetails.Criteria.AddCondition("new_employeeleavecalculation", ConditionOperator.Equal, detailsRef.Id);
```